# Estou a fazer um código php para fazer a media das provas e no final parecer aprovado, reprovado ou recuperação mas não sei o que esta a dar errado

Tags: php

```
 <?php 
$prova1 = 20;
$prova2 = 12;
$prova3 = 5;
  
  $media = ($prova1 + $prova2 + $prova3)/3;
echo "A média deu: $media";
if ($media >= 9,5)
{
echo "// Parabéns você foi aprovado";
}
elseif ($media > 8  && $media < 9,5)
{
echo "// Terá de ir a recuperação";
}
else ($media <= 8)
{
echo "// Você foi reprovado";
}
?>
```

Comment: No PHP o separador decimal é o ponto, então o número "nove e meio" é `9.5`, não `9,5`. Ao executar o código aparece o erro informando isso: "*syntax error, unexpected ',' ... on line 8*"

Comment: Aliás, `else` não tem condição... ele é o `else`...

Comment: E se as notas podem ser maior que 10, não é garantido que a média será de 0 a 10.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda . Por acaso o meu amigo falou-me isso do else mas nós nao nos lembramos  que era preciso ponto em vez de virgula

Answer (score -1):

temos 2 problemas nesse código os números em PHP utilizamos . e não , para separar os decimais. o outro problema é seu else não pode ter valor ou altere para elseif ou remova o ().

```html
<?php 

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$prova1 = 20;
$prova2 = 12;
$prova3 = 5;
  
$media = ($prova1+$prova2+$prova3)/3;

 echo "A média deu: ".$media;
 if ($media >= 9.5)
{
     echo "// Parabéns você foi aprovado";
 }
elseif ($media > 8  && $media < 9.5)
{
    echo "// Terá de ir a recuperação";
}
elseif ($media <= 8)
{
    echo "// Você foi reprovado";
}

?>
```